# search for string and remove full line from phpMyAdmin WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i want search for lines and if find text in it remove full line

example of line in wp posts

```
<strong>read more:text of post</strong>
```

with search for words read more

i try search and replace with this code but im poor with regexp

`

UPDATE `wp_posts`

```
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE( `post_content`, '<span(.*?)((id=[^ ]+|class=[^ ]+|style=[^ ]+)\s*)+(.*?)\>(.*?)<\/span\>', '<span$1$4>$5</span>');`
```

Comment: Probably easier to read it from the database, replace it at the script level, and update the column.

Comment: How do you define a line in a html document?

Comment: never see who replace and find text

Comment: text change after : so read more is search word and after it to end tag remove